# Change the file name in Audit4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, audit4j

I am using Audit4j for audit logging purpose. It generates the file in the given path with the name **Audit_Log_yyyy_mm-dd** format. I want to change the file name as **MyFileName_yyyy-mm-dd**. Is it possible to do this ?.

I have tried to set the file prefix using the following code. But it did not work.

```
FileAuditHandler fileAuditHandler = new FileAuditHandler();
fileAuditHandler.setPath(AUDIT_FILE_LOCATION);
fileAuditHandler.setAuditFilePrefix(applicationName);
```

Please help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

At present time there is no solution.

In version 2.5.0 the property auditFilePrefix of FileAuditHandler in not taken in account.
This is a bug.

I have open a request in Audit4j-core project in Github
https://github.com/audit4j/audit4j-core/issues/80